# Which PSU do I need for this setup?

Tags: graphics-cards, power-supply

I want to mine some altcoins via NiceHash with two graphics cards 24/7 or at least in the evening and night. I was wondering if my PSU is good enough for my setup since I want to buy an extra graphics card. My PC setup:

CORSAIR RMx Series RM750x - 2018 Edition

MSI Z490-A PRO Motherboard

NZXT Kraken X63 RGB Liquid coolingsystem

Adata XPG SX8200 Pro 1TB SSD

Intel Core i7 10700K

G.Skill Ripjaws V F4-3200C14D-32GVK

Asus ROG Strix GeForce RTX 3080

GeForce RTX 3060 TI

Can my 750W PSU start and sustain this setup or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No

Longer answer, maybe

With only a 3080, your system would draw around 550W. Add 200W for the 3060ti, and you get 750W. If RTX 3000 series would not have mega power draw spikes and nothing is OCed, 750W is just enough for you. Because RTX 3000 series have mega power draw spikes, I would reccomend going at least 200W above that (+-1000W).

Also, to stay under that 1000W mark, try undervolting your graphics cards a bit in MSI Afterburner. It should not impact performance, it can even improve performance and it reduces power usage.

For power supply brands, I would reccomend Corsair and Seasonic.

Comment: What happens when my graphics cards have mega power draw spikes? Would it shut off with my 750W PSU?

Comment: yes, if your psu has over current protection (most have). Otherwize, it can explode.

Answer (score 0):

You can try an online PSU calculator. They are accurate enough.

Example: https://outervision.com/power-supply-calculator

Answer (score 0):

I believe the PSU is slightly underpowered for this setup. I would recommend a 1000w PSU since you have two cards on there and the RTX 3000 series cards love drawing a lot of power. This power supply is on the high end of what you'd need to cover the system, but the PSU will be more efficient here than if you're putting the PSU to max load. I would recommend the power supplies below, as my family have variations of these and love them with no issues. If you can afford the second PSU, I would recommend that one over the first due to it being more efficient, which could be helpful in an always-on mining rig.

[Corsair RM1000x 80+ Gold PSU](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/corsair-rmx-series-rm1000x-80-plus-gold-fully-modular-atx-power-supply-black/6459246.p?acampID=0&cmp=RMX&irclickid=Sjm0qDVqfxyLTooX4hWrN1IrUkB3QwUfIzsTUU0&irgwc=1&loc=PCPartPicker&mpid=79301&ref=198&skuId=6459246)
[Be Quiet Straight Power 11 1000w 80+ Titanium](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1556367-REG/be_quiet_bn644_straight_power_11_platinum.html)

Comment: BTW, the "Be Quiet" psu's really do live up to their brand name.

Comment: In my opinion the 1000W would be overkill.
When mining it's recomended not to run the gpu's at 100%  when reducing the power limit to either 75 to 80% it massively reduces the 3080 power usage. Due to the constant mining load there will also be less power spikes. Furthermore, depending on the mining client used, the cpu load would be minimal. Allowing for more overhead on the psu. From what I can see, the 750W could even be enough to cover the requirements.

Comment: @Stax, I personally bought an 850w Gold rated unit for my high-end gaming system and I've never heard that fan. I have a spare CM Hyper 212 knockoff with the BQ Silent Wings 3 fans and man, that's a quiet cooler with a good amount of airflow